# Internal search engine for webmatrix 3

Tags: razor, full-text-search, search-engine, lucene.net, webmatrix

I'm trying to implement an internal search engine for my webmatrix website, it will serach through my database(SQL CE) for similarity and return results. Someone suggested me to use lucene.net because of how powerful it is. I cannot find documentation on implementing lucene.net with webmatrix, only implementation on asp.net with VS 2015. Can anyone guide me on implementing it on webmatrix? Or does anyone have any good suggestion for internal search engine? Or it would be easier to write my own search algorithm? Thanks!

Comment: Are there any suggestions?

Comment: still need help on this question if anybody got an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use our product [SearchUnit Community](https://keyoti.com/products/search/dotNetWeb/index.html), there's a free version for small websites.  I believe you'll find it easier to use than Lucene, and although we don't have documentation specific to WebMatrix, the standard Javascript based usage should apply just the same.  The product uses ASP.NET on the backend.
For example if you look at the [quick start](https://keyoti.com/products/search/dotNetWeb/HtmlHelp6/UserGuide/Quick%20Start.htm), you'll see that you can crawl any web-site using the index manager tool.  Then you drop some Javascript onto your page, and hook up WCF for the backend search calls.

If it helps, the search engine uses Javascript/HTML on the front end to build the UI, and then communicates via AJAX/WCF to the backend service that does the searching.
You can run WCF with webmatrix, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/james_osbornes_blog/2010/07/30/webmatrix-iisexpress-beta-hosting-wcf-services/

If you're stuck you're welcome to post support questions on the [SearchUnit Community forum](https://keyoti.com/support/default.aspx?g=topics&f=21)